# PowerShell - Get the sum of the items in the array

Tags: arrays, windows, powershell, sum

I have an array which contains some letters and i want to write in a variable the concatenation of the letters, for example:

```
$letters = @("a","b","c","d","e")
$var = $letters[0]+$letters[1]+$letters[2] #...
```

How can i do it?

Comment: "the sum of the letters" - what does that mean? You want the string `"abcde"`? Or the numerical value 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5?

Comment: Can you please clarify what value you expect ```$var``` to contain afterwards? If you want the string ```"abcde"``` you can do this:  ```$var = new-object string(@(,$letters))```, but if that's the case your first line needs to quote the letters - i.e. ```$letters = @("a","b","c","d","e")``` otherwise you get a ```Missing argument in parameter list.``` error.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yeah, sorry. I mean I want the string "abcde"

Comment: @mclayton I want the string "abcde". Anyway I wrote that script at the moment, sorry.

Comment: `$letters = @('a','b','c','d','e'); $var = $letters -join ''`